# Easiest Way to Send Lumens to Several Addresses?

Tags: xlm

I'm not looking to start writing programs here (hopefully!! lol)...just a one-off "airdrop" (I guess it is called) to a list of public addresses, probably stored in a .csv text file.

I'm going to issue a community coin for about 1000 people, whom I will tell to make trustlines in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider and determine before issuing a custom asset. Read the docs, but you likely want an issuing and dispersing account. You will need enough XLM to support the trustlines. You may want to host a toml file to 'vouch' for the coin. You may want issuing limits, etc. Are there any 'rules' to enforce? (Can users transfer to users you don't know about? Do coins get circulated or consumed? Etc.)

If any of your user accounts are external custodial wallets (think Coinbase, etc.), you may need to ensure the memo field is correctly used. If you are the custodian you may need to fund them and support the trustline fees. (Small, but still must be done).

Once you decide on all these things, you could execute it all manually with the public horizon server.

1k users might not be too bad, but it'll still take quit a few hours with fast typing. Way too prone to errors for my taste, and I am too lazy myself. ;)

I recommend code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and insights.  I think I have a grasp of most of that, except the "memo field" part, that I don't get.  Regarding distribution, what I'm now thinking is to use the cURL command line interface on Windows and write a very short DOS or BASH batch file with a loop...probably about 6 lines total.  No way am I typing in 1000 public keys!!  lol

Comment: You'll need to sign the transaction. Don't think that is possible from a command line.  Memo is often used like a sub-account for custodial wallets. So if 2 people both have an account with Coinbase, you send tx1 to user1 at acct1:memo A   and tx2 to user2 at acct1:memo2.   Acct1 is Coinbase's acct, essentially, and they track user accounts with memo.